# Jest : return function using mockImplementation

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I want to mock the function using jest as follows :

```
this.byId("ABC").getAggregation("EFG")
                    .setVisiblePagesCount(this.test());
```

and I thought this has to be implemented as follows :

```
controller.byId = jest.fn().mockImplementation(function() {
                    return getAggreegation = jest.fn().mockImplementation(function() {
                        return setVisiblePagesCount = jest.fn();
                })
})
```

but seems not the case ? Any thoughts that how to do the same ?

Comment: You're not returning an _object_ from the mock implementation, just the result of an assignment. Also the complexity of the API you're interacting with suggests mocking it isn't a great idea.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so how should we deal with the same ?

Comment: Abstract that interface behind a simpler one you own and _can_ mock for unit testing, coupled with integration testing that the whole thing works together.